# Reset radio buttons in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

I have three radio buttons in one button group. I want, on `JButton` click, for the radio buttons to be reset so they're unfilled. I've tried the logical suggestions that come up with you type `.set` and all of the booleans didn't do what I wanted it to do. So if you have suggestions that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried setSelected(false); setContentAreaFilled(false); button.revalidate(); button.firePropertyChange(null, true, false); setIconPainted(false); and a few others I can't recall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`ButtonGroup#clearSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection--)

For example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JRadioButton[] buttons;
        private ButtonGroup buttonGroup;

        public TestPane() {
            buttons = new JRadioButton[] {
                new JRadioButton("Nuclear"),
                new JRadioButton("Gas"),
                new JRadioButton("Stream"),
                new JRadioButton("Peddle"),
                new JRadioButton("Electric")
            };
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
            for (JRadioButton btn : buttons) {
                add(btn, gbc);
                buttonGroup.add(btn);
            }

            JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
            add(clear, gbc);

            clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonGroup.clearSelection();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh you are amazing. I totally forgot to check what I could do with the button group itself. Thank you :D